# Git reset soft no funciona

Tags: git

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual tengo 2 commits de git, ahora quiero hacer un reset soft del ultimo commit para modificar algo, pero al momento de hacerlo se ve que no cambia nada. Hago un git log para ver si cambio algo pero el commit sigue ahi, hasta intento hacer git status pero me dice que no hay modificaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más claro? ¿Qué pretendes hacer con `git reset`? `git reset` solo puede deshacer commits locales, que no figuran en el remoto. Además, `"dca769c"` es el commit en el que ya estás. Tienes que indicar otro commit, como `"5fee129"` o lo que es lo mismo `HEAD~1`, un commit antes de donde está posicionado el **HEAD**.

Comment: @Mateo Acabo de terminar el header responsive, y necesito modificarle una cosa que me falto agregarle. Ese commit ya lo subi a github. Como tengo que hacer ahora para modificar ese commit tanto de forma local como para el repositorio de github

Answer (score 1):

Ya que lo que quieres modificar es el último commit, no hay que hacer ningún reset. Solo haz las modificaciones que quieres incluir en el commit, agrega al index y acomete con `--amend`

```
# editar los archivos que necesites
git add archivo1 archivo2
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Podrías hacerlo mismo con un reset soft, pero no es necesario.... y lo tienes que hacer al commit anterior:

```
git reset --soft 5fee129 # por favor, esa pregunta no necesita una imagen sino texto, seria bueno que el OP hiciera el cambio en la pregunta
# edita lo que necesites
git add archivo1 archivo2
git commit -m "aqui tienes que especificar el comentario"
```

Una pequeña explicación creo que vale la pena: `git reset --soft` mueve el *apuntador* de la rama en la que estés trabajando al sitio indicado **pero** no toca ni el index ni el árbol de trabajo. Por ello, para que el truco funcione, hay que hacer un soft reset al commit anterior, para que todo lo que hay en el último commit más todo lo que hayas editado en el árbol de trabajo se vea como cosas pendientes de acometer en un nuevo commit.

De cualquiera de las 2 formas, vas a tener que hacer un `git push -f` para que el cambio se refleje en la rama remota, ya que ella está parada en un commit que se está eliminando de la historia.

Comment: Mateo hace la salvedad de que si ya empujaste al repositorio, se debe hacer un revert. Esto no es _obligatorio_, ya que se puede hacer como lo estoy indicando en la respuesta.... _pero_, ciertamente, no es recomendable reescribir la historia de ramas compartidas si hay más gente trabajando sobre dicha rama (ppr ejemplo, un _feature branch_? Mientras no sea mezclado en alguna rama compartida puede recibir cualquier cambio que involucre reescribir la historia sin problemas.... y si alguien se montó en dicha rama antes de que se mezclara es _responsabilidad de dicha persona_ salir del dilema).

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que ya pusheaste el commit tienes 2 opciones:

- Revertir los cambios con `git revert` seguido del commit a revertir. Lo cual creará un nuevo commit quitando los cambios que produjo.
- Deshacer los cambios. Según [esta publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31937298/13419694):

  Vuelve a un commit previo con `git reset`. Este será el último commit que quedará en el repositorio. Los más recientes serán eliminados.

  Haz los cambios necesarios y crea un nuevo commit (opcional).

  Ahora sube los cambios a la fuerza:

  ```
  git push -f <nombre-remoto> <nombre-rama>
  ```

  Por ejemplo:

  ```
  git push -f origin main
  ```

  No es recomendable hacerlo en repositorios compartidos.

Comment: Mateo, esa no es la sintaxis de un push. Seria `git push -f el-remoto la-rama-local-y-remota` o `git push -f el-remoto rama-local:rama-remota`